# Probability of k random integers being coprimes

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, coprime

In [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality) of the Wikipedia article on coprime integers, it is stated that:

> More generally, the probability of $k$ randomly chosen integers being coprime is $1/\zeta(k)$.

where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Although there is no proof of this, the statement follows a fleshed out explanation about the probability of two random integers being coprime. Briefly, it proceeds as follows:

- The probability of any integer being divisible by some other integer $p$ is $1/p$ (because every $p^\mathrm{th}$ integer is).
- The probability that two random integers (chosen independently) are both divisible by $p$ is $1/p^2$.
- For a given integer, being divisible by primes $p$ or $q$ are two independent events, and hence the probability of both being true is $1/pq$.
- Therefore the probability that two random integers are coprimes (i.e. that they are *not* both divisible by *any* prime) is:

$$
\prod_{\text{prime } p} 1 - \frac{1}{p^2} 
= \left( \prod_{\text{prime } p} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-2}} \right)^{-1}
= \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} \approx 0.61
$$

And it seems straightforward to apply the same reasoning for $k$ integers:

- The probability of $k$ random integers chosen independently being divisible by $p$ is $1/p^k$.
- Hence the probability that they are all coprimes is obtained when they are not all divisible by any prime:

$$
\prod_{\text{prime } p} 1 - \frac{1}{p^k} 
= \frac{1}{\zeta(k)}
$$

**My problem with this is one of intuition**; intuitively, considering several integers should increase the chances of two of them having a common prime factor, and therefore the probability of $k$ random integers being coprime should asymptotically decrease with $k$. However I think $1/\zeta$ is increasing on $[1, \infty)$, and quickly converges to 1. **Where am I going wrong? And what is the right way to think about this?**

Comment: [This **Math Overflow** post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97041/what-is-the-probability-that-two-numbers-are-relatively-prime) might serve useful, by the way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $N = 3$, the definition of three integers being coprime is that the highest common factor of the three integers is $1$. In other words, for any prime $p$, at least one of my three integers is not divisible by $p$. Thus, as $N$ increases, it becomes **easier** for coprimality to be satisfied.

I think you are thinking about the integers being **pairwise coprime** (i.e. each pair of integers is a coprime pair). This is a different notion from the one discussed in the article, and, as you point out, pairwise coprimality becomes harder to satisfy as $N$ increases.

Comment: That was exactly my mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you please refer to something / briefly explain the case of pariwise coprimality?

Comment: @Sheljohn "Coprime" means "for each $p$, at most $N-1$ of my integers are divisible by $p$". "Pairwise coprime" means "for each $p$, at most one of my integers are divisible by $p$.

Comment: @Sheljohn The probability of none of the integers being divisible by $p$ is $\left(1 - \frac 1 {p}\right)^N$. The probability of precisely one of the integers being divisible by $p$ is $N \frac 1 p \left( 1 - \frac 1 p\right)^{N-1}$ (the factor of $N$ appears because there are $N$ integers to choose from). So the probability that at most one of my integers is divisible by $p$ is $\left( 1 + \frac{N-1}{p}\right)\left( 1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^{N-1}$. And the probability that my $N$ integers are pairwise coprime is $\prod_p \left( 1 + \frac{N-1}{p}\right)\left( 1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)^{N-1}$.

Comment: I meant the probability that $k$ random integers would be pairwise coprimes :) Intuitively in the limit, it seems related to the probability that the $k$ integers would themselves be prime numbers.

Comment: Yes, see the previous comment.

Comment: Strictly speaking there is no uniform probability distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ hence the argument above should be applied to $[1,N] \cap \mathbb{Z}$, and then $N$ alowed to tend to infinity.

So the argument is talking about the limiting case, informally.